# Can't Find Style Sheets

Tags: sharepoint-designer, style.css

I am in SharePoint Designer at a site level 'All Files' can't find any folder related to style sheets.

I read that I should be in the site collection but I don't think one can load the site collection in SharePoint designer so not sure what that's all about.

I know it should be here, I used to see it on past projects and images on the interwebs its clearly there. just not for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site collection behaves like any other site in SharePoint Designer. It differs in that it has a few more libraries, e.g. it will have a library called "Style Library" in which you can  find and manage CSS files that apply to the whole site collection.

Many system level CSS files are stored on the SharePOint server and you will not be able to access these with SharePoint Designer.

Comment: thanks I thought I could not open the site collection because I had the URL wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer copy and paste below I forgot I am not on a publishing site

Style libraries only get added automatically to Publishing sites. If you just create a normal blank site, team site, etc., you might have a folder available to you in SharePoint Designer, but it won't be an actual SharePoint Library called Style Library the way you would have one if you enabled the Publishing feature on your site.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f5e0229-7a68-4cf7-9ec6-bf1ffcdc6620/no-style-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious